# How can I guarantee message ordering from the consumer side?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say that the producer sends 3 events in a specific order (and the order is very important) for 3 different consumers, all these events are going to the same topic and all the consumers are subscribed to that topic.

Let's assume that all the consumers are down, and they all are going to be up again together.

How can I make sure that these consumers will maintain the order of the events?

Comment: Are the 3 consumers part of the same group (`group.id`) ? If yes, we don't really care if there are 1 / 2 / 3 / ... consumers. Or maybe you want message 1 processed specifically by consumer A, once message 1 is processed, you want message 2 to be processed by consumer B, and so on and so forth. Which one are you looking for ?

Comment: I want message 1 processed specifically by consumer A, once message 1 is processed, you want message 2 to be processed by consumer B, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your produces data is not belongs to one partition, Then consuming
  order can not be guaranteed.
- So if there is multiple partition for your topic then you need to consider about the partitioner  of the producer. If it is `hash-based` then messages with same key are produced to the same partition and consumer is guaranteed to consume them in order.

Comment: While correct, this assumes the producer batch request was ordered already and there was no retries between any two producer requests

Comment: So, just adding these events to the same topic will ensure that event 2 will not be consumed before event 1 has already been **read and finished**?

Comment: Same partition.

Comment: But in this case, consumer 1 will read event 1 first, then consumer 1 will also read event 2 and 3. Here other consumers will stay idle and did not actually do anything and consumer 1 will do all the work.

Comment: Maximum number of consumers for a consumer group should be equal to number of partition in the topic.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `--from-beginning` flag in your command, like: `$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic quickstart-events --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

Check [1.3 Quick Start](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart), and find `STEP 5: READ THE EVENTS`.

Also, you could get some useful info in the same link provided above.

Comment: If the topic has more than one partition, there's no guarantee this returns consistent order

Comment: Even if you read all the messages on the topic, you will never guarantee the order unless you add them to the same partition, in this case only one consumer will be responsible for reading these messages.

That is what I have learned so far.